# Filtering DataView with RX

Tags: .net, wpf, system.reactive, dataview, reactive

I am building a WPF application and I am stuck at the point when I need to filter a ListBox. I obviously have a textbox for the user to put the filter string in, and I am using RX to handle it.

```
 filterBox = Observable.FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventHandler, TextChangedEventArgs>(
            h => this.filterText.TextChanged += h,
            h => this.filterText.TextChanged -= h)
            .Throttle(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 750))
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .Subscribe(t => this._datacontext.DoFiltering(this.filterText.Text));
```

filterText is the TextBox. DoFiltering is a method in the viewmodel to do the filtering.

```
  public void DoFiltering(string t)
    {
        DataView vw = _bks.clienteView;
        vw.RowFilter = String.Format(@"(CFPIva LIKE '%{0}%' OR
                                        Nominativo LIKE '%{0}%')", t);
        Dati = vw;
    }
```

Dati is a property to which the ListBox ItemsSource property is binded.

The problem is that the ListBox can contain tens of thousands of elements and, from what I have understood, my code executes the filtering on the main thread. This could hang the UI.

So, how can I execute the filtering in another thread/task? Preferably using RX and nothing more? The Do operator?

Also, how the filtering in DataView works under the hood? It starts the filtering operation as soon as I set the RowFilter property?